# how to remove whitspace while pasting in edittextbox?

Tags: android, android-edittext, removing-whitespace

I need to write **"tingting"** in an editbox in my application.first i wrote **ting** after that i copied the text and paste it in the same editbox.but the value in the edit text is **"ting ting".**
 .I know how to remove whitespace while taking the value from edit text.but i want to remove the whitespace while pasting text in the edit box
 how can i do that?  given below is my edittextbox.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/list_AddNewtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/list_stdcenterelement"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|actionGo|actionDone"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:maxLength="1000" />
```

Comment: I guess u r manually copy pasting it.

Comment: i am using device's copy and paste features

Comment: is it possible to use textChangeListener or something like that?

Comment: nobody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String str=list_AddNewtext.getText().trim();
list_AddNewtext.setText(str);
```

Comment: in which event i have to write this code.problem arise when i paste the text.is der any event for paste function?

Comment: it is crashing when i add textwatcher :(

Comment: You want to automate copy process?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
String str = list_AddNewtext.getText().toString();
String _newstr = str.replace(" ", "");
```

use _newstr its give tingting output

you put this code in your onclickListner event